# What's going on with this dash '-' thing?

Tags: linux, io-redirection, arguments, output, dash

I was trying to export the Python environment requirements and this is what I intended to do:

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

However I mistakenly typed this instead:

```
conda list -e -> requirements.txt
```

It still works, but the file is having fewer lines in the content. I want to know what exactly happened. I searched, but I couldn't find an explanation on the `-` in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-e` option [doesn't take any argument after it](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html#Named%20Arguments), so the `-` is just a regular argument to `list`. The first and only [positional argument `conda list` has](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html#Positional%20Arguments) is a regular expression, which causes it to

> List only packages matching this regular expression.

In your case, it will have listed only packages matching `-` (so, containing a hyphen in their name). That output was then redirected into `requirements.txt` as you intended. It will be shorter than `conda list -e`'s output because there are some non-matching packages that aren't included.